# Am I calculating battery life expectancy correctly for this RF receiver?

Tags: batteries, current

I have this [RF remote/receiver](http://www.spotix.com/manuals/Skytech/Skytech-3301-Installation-and-Operating-Instruction-Manual.pdf). Though the manual says battery life for the receiver is at least 12 months, I easily get 2 years of operation on a fresh set of batteries.  The receiver 4 uses AAA batteries, so that should be 6V at 1200 mAh. Assuming there are external factors like self-discharging, the battery life is further decreased by 15%.  I'm basing my calculations from [this calculator](http://oregonembedded.com/batterycalc.htm).

```
Battery Life in years = Battery Capacity in mAh / Current in mAh / 24 / 365 * (1 -.85)
```

So based upon a 2 year life span (and assuming the .15 constant is correct) is it fair assume that the receiver is drawing **on average** around 58uA?

I realize I'm making some assumptions here, like the .15 constant.  And I'm fairly sure the receiver is operating in sleep mode and waking up, but I want to make sure I understand this before addressing those assumptions.

Comment: Seems like a good estimate. If you need to know for sure, measure it.

Comment: could be hard to measure if you don't have a data logger.

Comment: In the manual it says the receiver operates on AA batteries.Note that batteries have a voltage-mAh discharge curve,which means that as you consume the battery energy,their total voltage drops.The linked document says that the receiver must be supplied with at least 5.3V.Have you considered this?

Comment: You have a mistake: "Current in mAh", unit of current is mA, not mAh

Comment: Self discharge is no external factor, it is internal of the battery.

Comment: You wrote (1 - 0.85), but did you mean (1 - 0.15)?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are doing it wrong. your calculations are only correct **if** the RF remote is constantly working and sending signals. And I think the 12 months is estimated by the manufacturer for an average household usage of the product.

Comment: OP's calculation of 58 uA avg. is still correct when **his personal use pattern** of the remote control is the consideration, because a few bursts of high current consumption and long period of no current consumption is still equivalent to a very low constant current consumption on average. So the result can be described as entirely correct. Nevertheless, I agree that it's probably a bit misleading:  If the remote is used more frequently by someone else, the calculated average current consumption should also increase.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver seems to be a bad construction regarding battery life. Four AA cells are used but the minimum voltage is 5.3 V. So a cell may be discharged from 1.55 V to 1.325 V only. The remaining capacity from 1.325 V down to 0.8 or 0.9 V may not be used. Instead of 4 cells only the receiver should use 6 or even 7 cells together with a low drop high efficiency switching regulator. But for a rf receiver the switching regulator may be a problem. But 9 or even 10.5 V from fresh cells may be too much for the receiver. A linear regulator to 5.3 V would waste a lot of the battery capacity. To design a receiver to work with the full voltage swing from 10.5 down to 5.3 may be difficult and affect frequency stability. Using 6 or even 7 instead of only 4 batteries is very uncommon for those kind of electronics.